# Swift: Protocol Constraint on iVar + Equatable

Tags: swift, protocols, nsviewcontroller, equatable

## Context

Consider this protocol and class in Swift 5.9:

```
protocol SpinnerHosting: AnyObject
{
    var spinnerItem: SpinnerItem { get }
}
```

```
final class MyViewController: NSViewController
{
    var activeChild: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting)? = nil

    
    func pushChild(_ incomingChild: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting))
    {
        // #1
        if incomingChild != activeChild {
           ...
        }

        // #2
        if incomingChild != activeChild! {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

At point #1, Swift throws this error:

```
Type 'any NSViewController & SpinnerHosting' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

At point #2 (ignore the unsafe unwrapping) it throws this one:

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two 'any NSViewController & SpinnerHosting' operands
```

## Question:

I understand why Protocols aren't `Equatable`. But I do NOT understand why the compiler thinks this isn't. Here, `SpinnerHosting` is constrained to `AnyObject`, which means reference types and therefore pointer-equality. But the same errors persist if I constrain the Protocol to `NSViewController` itself, which *definitely* surprises me because `NSViewController` is equatable.

I'm just trying to say: "Whatever `NSViewController` is going to occupy `activeChild` must have a `spinnerItem` property." (I realize I can do it with a subclass; that isn't my question.)

I've just seen this pattern: `var foo: ([Class] & [Protocol])` in several Apple source examples and I don't see a good reason why this can't be `Equatable`.

Comment: Bottom line is that AnyObject doesn't extend Equatable. If you want to compare object references there is a special operator for that, `===`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Right! But NSObject (and therefore NSViewController) work with ==, which is why I was surprised that changing the protocol conformance from `AnyObject` to a concrete class under NSObject didn’t resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `activeChild` should be `Equatable`

You are right, `NSViewController` inherits from `NSObject` which conforms to `Equatable`.
So, every subclass of `NSViewController` is still `Equatable`.

As a consequence a variable of type `NSViewController`, regardless from additional conformance requirements, is still `Equatable`.

✅ Infact, this code compiles just fine.

```
protocol SpinnerHosting: AnyObject { }
class MyViewController: NSViewController, SpinnerHosting { }
var a: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting) = MyViewController()
var b: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting) = a
print(a == b)
```

❌ The problem arises when we make `a` and `b` optional.

```
protocol SpinnerHosting: AnyObject { }
class MyViewController: NSViewController, SpinnerHosting { }
var a: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting)? = MyViewController()
var b: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting)? = a
print(a == b) // Type 'any NSViewController & SpinnerHosting' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

Now we get your error

## Wait, but `Swift Conditional Conformance` allows us to compare optional!

> The most noticeable benefit of conditional conformance is the ability for types that store other types, like Array or Optional, to conform to the Equatable protocol.

https://www.swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/

Right, you can equate 2 optionals if they hold 2 generic elements that can be equated

✅

```
protocol SpinnerHosting: AnyObject { }
class MyViewController: NSViewController, SpinnerHosting { }
var a: NSViewController? = MyViewController()
var b: NSViewController? = a
print(a == b)
```

However, it seems the Swift compiler is unable to infer `Equatable` conformance when `Existential Types` and `Conditional Conformance` are involved.

✅ You can help the Swift compiler adding an explicit casting

```
protocol SpinnerHosting: AnyObject { }
class MyViewController: NSViewController, SpinnerHosting { }
var a: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting)? = MyViewController()
var b: (NSViewController & SpinnerHosting)? = a
print(a as NSViewController? == b as NSViewController?)
```

Now it works.

[image]

## Here's another example

We can do a test replacing `Optional` with `Array` (which similarly benefits of `Conditional Conformance`).

✅ This compiles.

```
let list: [NSViewController] = []
list == list
```

❌ But as we add existential types to the party, the `Conditional Conformance` breaks

```
let list: [NSViewController & Codable] = []
list == list // Type 'any NSViewController & Codable' (aka 'any NSViewController & Decodable & Encodable') cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

Hope it helps.